# Duda al convertir un valor doble en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una inquietud al intentar convertir un valor a `double` en `C#`, resulta que desde una tabla en una base de datos de `oracle` estoy trayendo en una cadena un valor, pero este viene como cadena, más específicamente de un arreglo, para mayor claridad muestro el arreglo de donde lo estoy obteniendo:

```
ArrayLineas[min].Split('|')[1].ToString();
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente valor:

> 243358.9085285

Ahora bien necesito pasar dicho valor a una variable de tipo `double`, pero cuando hago un casting a `Double`, el valor me queda :

> 481696812935 (es decir que pierde sus puntos decimales).

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
double obtenerValor=Convert.ToDouble(ArrayLineas[min].Split('|')[1]).ToString("#,##.00");
```

La pregunta sería, como hago para que al momento de convertir esta cadena a double el valor no pierda sus puntos y sus comas decimales.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente el error se deba al uso del `.` como caracter decimal, intenta utilizar la siguiente instruccion:

```
double.Parse(ArrayLineas[min].Split('|')[1].ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

De esta manera evitas que se tome en cuenta si el caracter decimal es un punto o una coma.

Otra opcion podria ser que intentes reemplazar los `.` en tu cadena decimal con `,` y luego intentar la conversion de la manera que ya lo estas haciendo.

Comment: De antemano Muchísimas gracias IvanS95, ha sido la solución al problema, utilizando el double.Parse

Answer (score 0):

para que no pierda su punto y sus decimales simplemente no conviertas a double y luego a string + format, simplemente conviertelo a double

```c#
double obtenerValor=Convert.ToDouble(ArrayLineas[min].Split('|')[1]);
```